# Allowing one cell to grow whilst another shrinks to contents

Tags: html, css

I have this simple table row in HTML:

```
<tr>
   <th>Word</th>
   <td>£6.00</td>
</tr>
```

The row is a fixed width, and the number can be any size (so could be £6,000,000).  How can I keep the number shrink or expand to the required size, and allow the word to take up the full of the available space?

Answer (score 0):

Play with `min-width, max-width` CSS tags

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell that contains the number to have a `width:1px` it will stretch to fit its contents. Then set the first cell to have width auto, like so:

```
td:first-child{width:auto;}
td:last-child{width:1px;}
```

See it in action here - h[ttp://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/tXkqc/](http://ttp://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/tXkqc/)

Comment: Youre not wrong. [Hows about this](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/tXkqc/8/) - ive tested it in IE8 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
th {width:99%}
```

should force the first column to take all the available width and shrink the numbers column to minimum width